# Failed to start Grafana Service - Plugin folder permission denied

Tags: plugins, permissions, grafana

Attempting a fresh installation of Grafana on my new machine and ran into an issue while configuring my custom plugins folder.

`Failed to start grafana. error: stat /home/asw-user/plugins: permission denied`

**Issue**

Grafana service is able to start when I don't modify plugin folder location, but when I change it to a custom directory the service fails to start...

Followed all the steps in [docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v7.5/administration/configuration/#plugins), but am not sure what permission issue I have

**Log Output**  (/var/log/syslog)

```
Oct 12 11:47:30 asw grafana-server[5758]: t=2021-10-12T11:47:30-0500 lvl=info msg="Path Logs" logger=settings path=/var/log/grafana
Oct 12 11:47:30 asw grafana-server[5758]: t=2021-10-12T11:47:30-0500 lvl=info msg="Path Plugins" logger=settings path=/home/asw-user/plugins
Oct 12 11:47:30 asw grafana-server[5758]: t=2021-10-12T11:47:30-0500 lvl=info msg="Path Provisioning" logger=settings path=/etc/grafana/provisioning
Oct 12 11:47:30 asw grafana-server[5758]: t=2021-10-12T11:47:30-0500 lvl=info msg="App mode development" logger=settings
Oct 12 11:47:30 asw grafana-server[5758]: t=2021-10-12T11:47:30-0500 lvl=info msg="Connecting to DB" logger=sqlstore dbtype=sqlite3
Oct 12 11:47:30 asw grafana-server[5758]: t=2021-10-12T11:47:30-0500 lvl=info msg="Starting DB migrations" logger=migrator
Oct 12 11:47:30 asw grafana-server[5758]: t=2021-10-12T11:47:30-0500 lvl=info msg="migrations completed" logger=migrator performed=0 skipped=346 duration=422.573µs
Oct 12 11:47:30 asw grafana-server[5758]: t=2021-10-12T11:47:30-0500 lvl=info msg="Starting plugin search" logger=plugins
Oct 12 11:47:30 asw grafana-server[5758]: t=2021-10-12T11:47:30-0500 lvl=info msg="Registering plugin" logger=plugins id=input
Oct 12 11:47:30 asw grafana-server[5758]: Failed to start grafana. error: stat /home/asw-user/plugins: permission denied
Oct 12 11:47:30 asw grafana-server[5758]: stat /home/asw-user/plugins: permission denied
Oct 12 11:47:30 asw systemd[1]: grafana-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 12 11:47:30 asw systemd[1]: grafana-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 12 11:47:30 asw systemd[1]: grafana-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Oct 12 11:47:30 asw systemd[1]: Stopped Grafana instance.
Oct 12 11:47:30 asw systemd[1]: grafana-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 12 11:47:30 asw systemd[1]: grafana-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 12 11:47:30 asw systemd[1]: Failed to start Grafana instance.
```

**Version:** v8.2.1

Answer (score 0):

The user which runs the "grafana-server" must have permission to read/write/execute the "/home/asw-user/plugins" directory.